# Sitecore IP Geo location service lookups report

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting, geo-location

I would like to know where the following report read its content from, I have a data that doesn't make sense and I am trying to trouble shoot:

[image]

Comment: Data you are seeing not coming from Sitecore client, it coming from Sitecore's App service centre which is "https://apps.sitecore.net". Not sure but Sitecore may manage these request as per Licence ID.
You can see how this service works and send request - https://sitecorexpblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/29/sitecore-ip-geolocation-service/

Comment: I am not sure it will work but if you run following URL directly into browser it will give same UI interface. I don't have any client license to test it on my local -https://apps.sitecore.net/Sitecore.Apps.Client.aspx?Language=en&LicenseId=YourLicenceID&ConnectionTest=false&OkEndPoints=SacEndpoint-EmailDeliverySmtp587&ClientUrl=http://YourWebsite/sitecore/shell/Applications/Sitecore%20App%20Center.aspx?sc_bw=1&IsAdministrator=true&EndPoint=https://apps.sitecore.net/&SitecoreVersion=8.2.170614